# Solve $y''-x\ y=0$ with help of power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Below I've written my attempt at a solution. I've admit that I put way to much time on this specific problem. Is there a simpler way to solve these with help of power series?

$$y''-x\ y=0$$ 1. Assume that for this differential equation there exist a solution that can be written as a power series: $$y= \sum_{k\ \geq\ 0} a_k\ x^k \implies\\ y''=\sum_{k\ \geq\ 2}k\ (k-1)\ a_k\  x^{k-2}= \frac{2\ a_2}{x}\ +\ \sum_{k\ \geq\ 0} a_{k+3} (k+3)\ (k+2) x^{k+1} $$

So our differential eq. can be rewritten as: $$\frac{2\ a_2}{x}\ +\ \sum_{k\ \geq\ 0} (a_{k+3} (k+3)\ (k+2) - a_k)\ x^{k+1} = 0 \implies \\ \frac{2\ a_2}{x}=0 \ \ \wedge \ \ a_{k+3} (k+3)\ (k+2) - a_k = 0 \iff \\ a_2=0 \wedge \ a_{k+3}= \frac{a_k}{(k+3)(k+2)}$$

So we get the following: $$a_{3*1}= \frac{a_0}{3 * 2} \\a_{3*1+1}=\frac{a_1}{4*3} \\a_{3*1+2}=\frac{a_2}{5*4}=0 \implies \forall k \in \mathbb{N}: a_{3k+2}=0\\ a_{3*2}= \frac{a_3}{6*5}=\frac{a_0}{6*5*3*2}\\ a_{3*2+1}=\frac{a_4}{7*6}=\frac{a_1}{7*6*4*3}\\$$

It continues such that (this step took me quite some time to come to) $$a_{3k}= a_{3(k-1)} \ \frac{3k-2}{(3k)(3k-1)(3k-2)}=...=a_0 \frac{(3k-2) \ (3(k-1)-2)...7*4*1}{(3k)!}\\ a_{3k+1}=a_{3(k-1)+1} \ \frac{3k-1}{(3k+1)(3k)(3k-1)}=...=a_1 \frac{(3k-1)(3(k-1)-1)...8*5*2}{(3k+1)!}\\ a_{3k+2}=0$$

So finally the solution should be $$y(x)= a_0 \sum_{3k \ \geq \ 0} \frac{(3k-2) \ (3(k-1)-2)...7*4*1}{(3k)!} x^{3k}+ \\a_1 \sum_{3k+1} \frac{(3k-1)(3(k-1)-1)...8*5*2}{(3k+1)!} x^{3k+1}$$

Comment: See [Airy's equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html).